# How do I build custom Role properties for MVC5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I wanted to add custom properties to the default Role provider in MVC5, but I didn't know where to start.  My alternative is to build my own role management, but I wanted to use the built in stuff to get the most use out of it.  Has anyone come across any documentation for adding properties to Roles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*MVC5 supports new framework named 'ASP.NET Identity'. The new framework is much extensible. Read articles on [asp.net/identity](http://www.asp.net/identity) for more information. Try reading the 'next step' section of most articles.*

To answer how to add additional properties to Role, the IdentityRole class need to be inherited by custom class e.g. AppRole. In AppRole you can define additional role properties. The AppRole than need to be registered in ApplicationDbContext.

```
public class AppRole: IdentityRole
{
   public String Description { get; set;}
}
```

Take the above as an example snippet.

Tip: Try searching questions here in stackoverflow instead of just posting initial questions.